# Why is sizeof working for return types

Tags: c++, sizeof

I cannot find information about a behavior of sizeof (at least in gcc 4.6+). The following code works and produces the "expected" result (4, 1, 8), but I'm wondering why. I checked several questions but none show an example like this one.

```
#include<iostream>

int f1(int) {
  return 0;
}

char f2(char) {
  return 0;
}

double f3() {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(f1(0)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(f2('0')) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(f3()) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

An answer would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator can take a type or an expression as an argument and returns the size of its argument.  You're using expressions, so it returns the size of those expressions.  The expression is not evaluated at run-time — so the functions are never invoked.  But the correct (overloaded) function is used to determine the size of the result.

In a (now-deleted) comment, [user1919074](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919074/user1919074) said:

> `sizeof(f1)` would not work

*Brain fart*

<s>In C, `sizeof(f1)` would work since it would return the size of a pointer to function.</s>

The `sizeof()` operator can't be applied direct to a function name.  It has special rules, and when applied to an array, the normal 'decay' to a pointer doesn't occur.  Similarly, the change of a function name to a function pointer doesn't occur with `sizeof()`.  (Of course, you have to poke GCC hard with `-pedantic` to get it to give the warning/error; otherwise, it returns 1 as the size of the function.)

Comment: That's right. I found a description of the behavior in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof .Still, the syntax looks funny to me, since the function is, of course, never called. Thanks.

Comment: Uhmm, not really. sizeof(f1) wiuld produce an error like "error: ISO C++ forbids applying ‘sizeof’ to an expression of function type [-fpermissive]", as explained also in other answers in this forum

Comment: Actually this reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof clearly states `sizeof cannot be used with function types` and it does indeed produce the error mentioned above http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4bf2b300a7b6d97c11a73fdfad6908fa-81f8fd6fe3d78f519fccff6a9c88a3de

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I goofed, and was fixing up my answer when you commented.

Comment: No problem, you still got my +1 yours was the first answer that actually explained how it works

Answer (score 2):

What is happening in the functions

```
int f1(int) {
  return int(0);
}

char f1(char) {
  return char(0);
}

double f1() {
  return double(0);
}
```

What is happening later.

```
std::cout << sizeof(int(0)) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(char('0')) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(double(0)) << std::endl;
```

Because you are printing the `sizeof` the `value` of what is **returned** from the function

Comment: I don't think this is what's happening. "std::cout << sizeof(double(U())) <<std::endl;" where U is some class gives an error. The expression is evaluated (compile time) and the right function is found. It's not 'char('0'), it's 'return of f1(char)'.

Answer (score 1):

[ISO/IEC 14882](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.2110-001/downloads/C++%20Standard%202003.pdf) on C++ says (section 5.3.3 - page 79):
says

> "The size operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function or incomplete type,..."

Also notice the compilation warning with the -pedantic option enabled...

```
warning: invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type
```

Answer (score 0):

f1 returns an integer which takes 4 bytes.
f2 returns a character which takes 1 byte.
f3 returns a double which takes 8 bytes.

So all sizeof() does is return the size of its argument.